# How to Update value in one table by coping it from another table in plsql ?

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is a simple example of what I need to do. In fact I want to Update value in one table by coping it from another table by using cursors in  plsql.

I take table f and table b as two examples:

```
f= 
1|Thom                                                                                                                                                                                              
2|Bob                                                                                                                                                                                               
3|Steven                                                                                                                                                                                            
5|Arthur



b= 
7|Nataly                                                                                                                                                                                              
9|Alfred
```

, where I need to insert the b 's tow lines in  first f two lines:

```
create table f (a number, b varchar2(10));

insert into f values (1,'Thom');
insert into f values (2,'Bob');
insert into f values (3,'Steven');
insert into f values (5,'Arthur');
commit;


create table b (c number, d varchar2(10));

insert into b values (7,'Nataly');
insert into b values (9,'Alfred');

commit;
create or replace procedure wco as

  cursor c_f is 
    select a,b from f  for update;
    v_a f.a%type;
    v_b f.b%type;

  cursor c_b is 
    select c,d from b;
    v_c b.c%type;
    v_d b.d%type;

begin
  open c_f;
    open c_b
      loop
        fetch c_f into v_a, v_b;
        exit when c_f%ROWCOUNT=c_b%RROWCOUNT;
        update f set a=v_c and b=v_d where current of c_f;
      end loop;
    close c_d:
  close c_f;
end;
/

exec wco;

select * from f;

drop table f;
```

The expected result (What i hope to have):

```
7|Nataly                                                                                                                                                                                              
9|Alfred                                                                                                                                                                                              
3|Steven                                                                                                                                                                                            
5|Arthur
```

But what I have now (as a result)is:

```
1|Thom                                                                                                                                                                                              
2|Bob                                                                                                                                                                                               
3|Steven                                                                                                                                                                                            
5|Arthur
```

How do I resolve this problem, I am a beginner with PLSQL, I would be very grateful if you could help me please.

Comment: PL/SQL is, of course, a language used with Oracle, not MySQL. I edited your tag.

Comment: @O.Jones Thank you

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Is it a homework assignment you've been given? If so, what are you supposed to be demonstrating with the solution? I ask, because it's not something that would often need to be done in real world (ie. overwrite the contents of the first X rows in table 1 with the X rows in table 2) - usually it would be merging rows based on some sort of join column (e.g. an ETL process updating customer details etc)

Comment: @Boneist  In fact it is real state of case and I am trying to improve my PLSQL skills

Comment: @tierrytestu does your example match your real-world scenario? I.e. are there one or more columns in common between your two tables?

Comment: My two table have the same type of columns, it is similar to that example, I just try to put the easiest example that I can imagine, in fact the little table o example contains the 4 rows and the big table contains 9 rows, so I need to replace the first fourth rows of the big table with the fourth table of  small table, because they have the best results,  that is the idea

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure compiles, but with errors;
In order to see compilation errors
run `show errors;` after compilation.

Change `open c_b` to  `open c_b;` (missing semicolon at the end)

Change `close c_d:` to `close c_b;` (correct name is c_b and semicolon instead of colon)

Change `exit when c_f%ROWCOUNT=c_b%RROWCOUNT;` to exit when `c_f%ROWCOUNT=c_b%ROWCOUNT;` (wrong `%RROWCOUNT;`)

`update f set a=v_c and b=v_d where current of c_f;`  This is wrong SQL syntax.
Should be `update table_name set column=value, column=value`;

It is important to provide descriptive names to your variables, so it would be easier to understand your logic.

As I understood you want to copy only second two rows from source table.

```
create table source_table (
    id number, 
    name varchar2(10));
/

insert into source_table values (1,'Thom');
insert into source_table values (2,'Bob');
insert into source_table values (3,'Steven');
insert into source_table values (5,'Arthur');
/

create table target_table (
       id number, 
       name varchar2(10));
/

insert into target_table values (7,'Nataly');
insert into target_table values (9,'Alfred');
/

create or replace procedure copy_tables  
AS
 begin
  FOR source_row IN (select id, name 
                  from source_table 
                  offset 2 rows)
    LOOP
      insert into target_table
       values(source_row.id, source_row.name);
    END LOOP;
end;
/

exec copy_tables;
/

select id, name from target_table;
/
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help , but I need to copy all the source table and put them  as first rows in the  target table, what I give you there is just an example.

Comment: this solution does not give me the expected result, It gives me only an array with two rows: 7|Nataly                                                                                                                                                                                              

                                          9|Alfred

Comment: @tierrytestu So you want to copy all rows from source to target? Your example shows only 2 rows.

Comment: yes , let''s suppose that I have in my source table n rows, so I want to replace the first n rows in my target table with the n rows in my source table.

Comment: What if you have less than n rows in target table?

Comment: so that is not true, I need all th n rows

Comment: So if it is less copy all from source to target?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need PL/SQL for this; it can be achieved in a single MERGE statement:

```
merge into f tgt 
  using (select coalesce(b1.id, f1.id) id, 
                coalesce(b1.name, f1.name) name, 
                f1.f_rowid 
         from   (select id, 
                        name, 
                        rowid f_rowid, 
                        row_number() over (order by id) rn 
                 from   f) f1 
                full outer join (select id, 
                                        name, 
                                        row_number() over (order by id) rn 
                                 from   b) b1 
                  on f1.rn = b1.rn) src 
    on (tgt.rowid = src.f_rowid) 
when matched then 
  update set tgt.id = src.id, 
             tgt.name = src.name 
  where tgt.id != src.id 
  or    tgt.name != src.name 
when not matched then 
  insert (tgt.id, tgt.name) 
  values (src.id, src.name);
```

See https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_FBPR7YCLFVWO7NGDXTLSP1R97.html for the test details (two examples; the target table has more and has fewer rows than the source table).

If you need to, you could add the above insert into a procedure, e.g.:

```
create procedure populate_target_table as
begin
  merge into f tgt 
    using (select coalesce(b1.id, f1.id) id, 
                  coalesce(b1.name, f1.name) name, 
                  f1.f_rowid 
           from   (select id, 
                          name, 
                          rowid f_rowid, 
                          row_number() over (order by id) rn 
                   from   f) f1 
                  full outer join (select id, 
                                          name, 
                                          row_number() over (order by id) rn 
                                   from   b) b1 
                    on f1.rn = b1.rn) src 
      on (tgt.rowid = src.f_rowid) 
  when matched then 
    update set tgt.id = src.id, 
               tgt.name = src.name 
    where tgt.id != src.id 
    or    tgt.name != src.name 
  when not matched then 
    insert (tgt.id, tgt.name) 
    values (src.id, src.name);
end;
/
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help, it is the first solution that gives me some good results, but in my real scenario I  have more than 2 lines from the source table(b),  so this solution insert oly the first and the last column,

Comment: @tierrytestu I'm not sure what you mean by "so this solution insert only the first and last column"? If the example in your question doesn't match your actual real-world scenario, then you should update your question to be more accurate. There's no point in us giving you answers to a question that isn't the one you really want us to answer!

Comment: I am really sorry, this solution insert for me the first and last rows only, not all the rows,

Comment: That isn't the case for me. I updated [my script](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_FBPR7YCLFVWO7NGDXTLSP1R97.html) to merge three rows into the target table containing a single row, and in the output 3 rows are shown to be in the target table now. I don't see what you're seeing.